# Cannot find executable for CFBundle for fresh project in Xcode 5.0

Tags: ios, xcode

After updating from Xcode 4.6 to Xcode 5.0 via software update I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x8c422e0 
</Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/CertUIFramework.axbundle> 
(not loaded)"
```

I've tried the following fixes mentioned in other threads on stack overflow but none of them help:

1. Repair permissions using Disk Utility from recovery partition or safe boot
2. Reset Content & Settings for the iOS Simulator
3. Clean, Clean build folder for the project
4. Removed DerivedData from ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

Even a fresh project generates the same error.

On the latest version of Mountain Lion 10.8.5

Please help!

Comment: However there is no answer yet.  Monitor this Apple Developer Forum post, where the answer is likely to appear first: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/204628?tstart=0

Comment: The recommended fix for the error in the original post by resetting the iOS simulator doesn't help

Comment: Which "post" are you referring to?  The SO one or the Apple Developer Forum one?

Comment: SO. The Apple Dev Forum one doesn't have a fix yet.

Comment: That's no reason to post a duplicate question. This Apple Dev Forum post suggests resetting the simulator for quitting: https://devforums.apple.com/message/863467#863467

Comment: Make sure you've selected a retina display device simulator.